# Making a user an admin user through a button without having the attribute accessible in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

From what I understand it would create a security flaw if I were to let my admin boolean in my users model be listed in attr_accessible. However I want a link on my show page that lets existing admin users grant admin privileges to other users. I was wondering how to go about doing this? My code in my show view for a user at the moment includes:

```
  <% if current_user.admin? && @user.admin == false %>
    <%= link_to "Make Administrator", '#', 
    data: { confirm: "Make this user an admin?" }, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% elsif current_user.admin? && @user.admin%>
    <%= link_to "Remove Administrator", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
  <% end %>
```

I'm not entirely sure what to put instead of the '#'? @user.toggle!(:admin) doesn't seem to work so any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since this is an action this should be a button, not an link.

```
<%= button_to user_path(@user), :method => :put ... %>
```

controller code

```
def update
 if params[:admin] 
   user.update_attribute(:admin, true)
   redirect_to ...
 end
...
end
```

or if you prefer to keep your logic in the model

```
def update
 ...
 if params[:admin]
  @user.make_admin
 end
 ...
end
```

model code

```
def make_admin
 self.update_column(:admin, true)
end
```

Comment: Ok I've tried this and it's not working, although I do get what it's meant to be doing...when I try to update the admin it just redirects to the root path instead of back to the users index. I'll post my code in a tick. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Whoops my bad it's redirecting because of a before filter I was using. My bad

Comment: no worries, I am glad everything works out. To explain simply, update_attribute does not issue a save event, so it doesn't check attr_accessible. Same with .update_column. If you wanted to make it check the attributes, for security reasons, you would use update_attributes, and self.attribute = * respectively.